# Save many to many relation via view model in entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework

I have two entities (TaskStep and Role) with many to many relation, I use a view model (named StepViewModel) to display taskstep and it's allowed Roles, StepViewModel is :

```
  public class StepViewModel
{
    public StepViewModel()
    {

    }
    public TaskStep TaskStep { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AllowedRole> AllowedRole { get; set; }

}
```

and I use this method to display taskstep:

```
 public static StepViewModel GetTaskStepData(int stepId)
    {
        using (var context = new WFContext())
        {

            return context.TaskSteps.Where(ts => ts.ID == stepId).Include(ts => ts.Roles)
                .Select(ts => new StepViewModel()
                {
                    AllowedRole = context.Roles.Select(r => new AllowedRole()
                    {
                        Role = r,
                        Allowed = ts.Roles.Select(x => x.ID).Contains(r.ID)
                    }).ToList(),
                    TaskStep = ts
                })
                .SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

but when I save the taskstep, it's roles changes don't save. My save method is :

```
public static void SaveTaskStep(StepViewModel stepViewModel)
    {
        using (var context = new WorkFlowContext())
        {

            //TaskStep taskStep = context.TaskSteps.Where(ts => ts.ID == stepViewModel.TaskStep.ID).Include(ts => ts.Roles).SingleOrDefault();

            TaskStep taskStep = stepViewModel.TaskStep;

            List<int> aRolesIDs = stepViewModel.AllowedRole.Where(ar => ar.Allowed == true).Select(ar => ar.Role.ID).ToList();
            List<Role> roles = context.Roles.Where(r => aRolesIDs.Contains(r.ID)).Include(r => r.AllowedTaskSteps).ToList();

            taskStep.Roles.Clear();
            foreach (Role role in roles)
            {
                if (context.Entry(role).State == EntityState.Detached)
                    context.Roles.Attach(role);

                taskStep.Roles.Add(role);
            }

            if (taskStep.ID == 0)
                context.TaskSteps.Add(taskStep);
            else
                context.Entry(taskStep).State = EntityState.Modified;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

if I get taskstep from db with include roles (like first -comment- line in save method), it work's well. but in this way, I have to make all taskstep field's changes manually. In addition when I assign taskstep to stepviewmodel,I use "include" but it's still doesn't work.what can I do to save stepViewModel roles?

Answer (score 0):

`context.TaskSteps.Attach(taskStep)` should work in your case

SaveTaskStep method:

```
using (var context = new WorkFlowContext())
{
  TaskStep taskStep = stepViewModel.TaskStep;   
  if (taskStep.ID == 0)
    context.TaskSteps.Add(taskStep);
  else
    context.TaskSteps.Attach(taskStep); //from this point EF start change tracking

//I just copy-pasted this part your code assuming it's correct
  List<int> aRolesIDs = stepViewModel.AllowedRole.Where(ar => ar.Allowed == true).Select(ar => ar.Role.ID).ToList();
  List<Role> roles = context.Roles.Where(r => aRolesIDs.Contains(r.ID)).Include(r => r.AllowedTaskSteps).ToList();

  taskStep.Roles.Clear();
  foreach (Role role in roles)
  {
     if (context.Entry(role).State == EntityState.Detached)
       context.Roles.Attach(role);

       taskStep.Roles.Add(role);
  }

  context.SaveChanges();
} // end of using (var context
```

Comment: It work's fine when taskstep insert, but not for edit taskstep(like my code).

Comment: @MasoumehKarvar did you call `Attach` before any other actions like in my example? Also make sure that in your `TaskStep` class `Roles` collection marked as `virtual`